# Need Help in writing complex sql query

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTableA
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    RegionId INT,
    DistrictId INT,
    NurseryDays INT,
    TransplantDays INT     
 )

INSERT #tmpTableA ([Id], RegionId,DistrictId,NurseryDays,TransplantDays) VALUES (1,1,NULL,2,2) 
INSERT #tmpTableA ([Id], RegionId,DistrictId,NurseryDays,TransplantDays) VALUES (2,1,2,NULL,2)
```

The output of the sample code is,

```
Id  RegionId    DistrictId     NurseryDays         TransplantDays
2     1            2               NULL              2
1     1            NULL             2                2
```

My desired result is,
1.)If RegionId and DistrictId exists then get the Transplant days of this combination else get the Transplant days for RegionId and DistrictId(NULL).

2.) If RegionId and DistrictId exists then get the Nursery days of this combination else get the Nursery days for RegionId and DistrictId(NULL).

### Desired Result:

```
NurseryDays        TransplantDays
 2                      2
```

Is this possible in single query ?

Thanks & Regards,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 0):

The description of your result and the actual result do not match. If you require the nursery days of the regionid and disctrictid from your data this should be null.

You will need to create a stored procedure as shown to get your results.

```
create PROCEDURE ProcGetDays 
    @regionid int
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @nurserydays int
declare @transplantdays int

select @transplantdays = transplantdays from tmpTableA where regionid=@regionid and districtid is not null
if @transplantdays is null
    select @transplantdays = transplantdays from tmpTableA where regionid=@regionid

select @nurserydays=nurserydays from tmpTableA where regionid=@regionid and districtid is not null
if @nurserydays is null
    select @nurserydays=nurserydays from tmpTableA where regionid=@regionid

select @nurserydays as nurserydays,@transplantdays as transplantdays


END
GO
```

If you need to use a temp table you will need to create this within the stored procedure for it to still be available. In the sample I used a permanent table.

END
GO

Answer (score 0):

First, use a filter that retrieves rows with a specific `RegionId` and a specific or NULL `DistrictId`. Then order the rows in such a way that the more specific row goes before the other one, and select the topmost row.

In SQL, it might read like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  NurseryDays,
  TransplantDays
FROM YourTable
WHERE RegionId = @RegionId
  AND (DistrictId = @DistrictId OR @DistrictId IS NULL)
ORDER BY
  CASE DistrictId
    WHEN @DistrictId THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END
;
```